# How to give separate variables in cloud formation with respect to environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

- I have 2 different security groups in stage and prod
- For lambda function I have to give SG1 if its stage and SG2 if its prod
- Do i need to write separate resources in template or I can given any conditional expressions
- My security group SG1 and SG2 is deployed from this template only

```
Conditions:
  IsEnvProd: Fn::Equals [ !Ref Env, 'prod' ]
  IsEnvStage: Fn::Equals [ !Ref Env, 'stage' ]
BackupLambda:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Function"
    Properties:
      Handler: "backup_lambda.lambda_handler"
      Role: !Ref Role
      Runtime: "python2.7"
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 120
      Code:
        S3Bucket: !Ref BucketWithLambdaFunction
        S3Key: !Ref PathToLambdaFile
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !Ref SG1 # if its stage(IsEnvStage)
          - !Ref SG2 # if its prod(IsEnvProd)
```

Comment: I feel you could have found this one by just googling it. But cloudformation provides a mapping section especially for situations like this. 
Documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/mappings-section-structure.html)

Comment: @Henk-JanUijterlinde, its not possible because in the mapping at top you cant give !Ref SG, it will throw template error, Forgot to mention Security group is deployed from the template only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [If](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-if):

```
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !If [IsEnvStage, !Ref SG1, !Ref SG2]
```